# JQuery .on function is not applied to elements loaded dynamically on page load

Tags: jquery, xslt

I have an accordion menu, when the link header is clicked, it loads the page with the secondary links.

When clicked the `.on('click')` is loaded before the HTML elements are loaded, so I have to click the link header twice to open the accordion menu.

```
$('.accordion-menu > li > a').on('click', function (e) {

    if ($(this).siblings('ul').length) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if ($(this).closest('li').hasClass('active')) {
            $(this).siblings('ul').slideUp('normal', function () {
                $(this).closest('li').removeClass('active');
            });
        } else {
            $(this).closest('.accordion-menu').find('> li.active ul').slideUp('normal', function () {
                $(this).closest('li').removeClass('active');
            });

            $(this).siblings('ul').slideDown('normal', function () {

            });
            $(this).closest('li').addClass('active');
        }
    }
});
```

HTML

When I click the header, it should load the page and add class active as below

[image]

But now it actually just loads the page and elements are created, class active is not added.
*See below "Find Jobs"*
[image]

So in the JQuery function (`$(this).siblings('ul').length`) is coming 0 first time, so no class is being added...
When I click the header second time, class is added and accordion is working fine.

I tried changing the  `$('.accordion-menu > li > a').on('click',function (e) {` but not helping...
Tried adding the function in XSLT (end of the file), currently its in separate JS file.

Thanks

Comment: Use a delegate. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8110934/direct-vs-delegated-jquery-on)

Answer (score 0):

Your code works but if the elements are created dynamically the event should be attached to the parent (if .accordion-menu is loaded on page load and then the links inside are added dynamically) you can make it like this: http://jsfiddle.net/56fg39he/

```
$('.accordion-menu').on('click', 'a', function (e) {

    if ($(this).siblings('ul').length) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if ($(this).closest('li').hasClass('active')) {
            $(this).siblings('ul').slideUp('normal', function () {
                $(this).closest('li').removeClass('active');
            });
        } else {
            $(this).closest('.accordion-menu').find('li.active ul').slideUp('normal', function () {
                $(this).closest('li').removeClass('active');
            });

            $(this).siblings('ul').slideDown('normal', function () {

            });
            $(this).closest('li').addClass('active');
        }
    }
});
```

If the whole accordion menu is loaded dynamically into the page you can make it like this http://jsfiddle.net/56fg39he/1/

```
$('body').on('click', '.accordion-menu a', function (e) {

    if ($(this).siblings('ul').length) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if ($(this).closest('li').hasClass('active')) {
            $(this).siblings('ul').slideUp('normal', function () {
                $(this).closest('li').removeClass('active');
            });
        } else {
            $(this).closest('.accordion-menu').find('li.active ul').slideUp('normal', function () {
                $(this).closest('li').removeClass('active');
            });

            $(this).siblings('ul').slideDown('normal', function () {

            });
            $(this).closest('li').addClass('active');
        }
    }
});
```

You can read more about [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

Comment: Its not working either way ..Thank u for detail example. when the title header is clicked ,the page loads and it looks like <li class="">
<a href="#">Plan Your Job Search</a>
<ul style="display: none;">
<li>
</ul>
</ul> But it has to be display:block and class="active" for first <li>.

Comment: accordion menu is not loaded dynamically , only the <ul> part under <a> link is loaded on page load .. so i want the event to be attached during the load , so that the accordion is open on first click

Comment: Before clicking the title header will be like <li>
<a target="" href="/JobSearch/FindJobs/find-jobs.aspx">Find Jobs</a>
</li> .. so when clicked it loads the page with the <ul>